# POST 404 not found React when trying to do Stripe checkout

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a problem when trying to implement stripe checkout. When I press the button that should send me to Stripe i get:

"POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/bookings/checkout-session/65a6c04df12519008999688c 404 (Not Found) bookingHandler @ SidePanel.jsx:9"

Can you please help me troubleshoot the problem?

Here's the bookingHandler:

```
const bookingHandler = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(
                `${BASE_URL}/bookings/checkout-session/${mechanicId}`,
                {
                    method: "post",
                    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token} `,},
                }
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            if (data.session.url) {
                window.location.href = data.session.url;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }
```

I've tried to change routes, checked controller for any errors, What can I set up I think I've tried

EDIT1:

Here's part of bookingController:

```
export const getCheckoutSession = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
        // pobierz aktualnie rezerwowanego mechanika
        const mechanic = await Mechanic.findById(req.params.mechanicId);
        const user = await User.findById(req.userId);

        // utwórz sesje płatności
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            mode: "payment",
            success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_SITE_URL}/checkout-success`,
            cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/mechanic/${mechanic.id}`,
            customer_email: user.email,
            client_reference_id: req.params.mechanicId,
            line_items: [
                {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: "pln",
                        unit_amount: mechanic.price * 100,
                        product_data: {
                            name: mechanic.name,
                            description: mechanic.bio,
                            images: [mechanic.photo],
                        },
                    },
                    quantity: 1,
                },
            ],
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide revelant code of your controller?

Comment: Yes of Course, I'll edit it in post right away

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem lies in the indexjs, which for some reason was having problem with import. After deleting it and manually entering import once again the route started to work